# Disposing NServiceBus bus instance in MVC 6

Tags: nservicebus, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous ASP.Net incarnations, NServiceBus examples state to create a Bus instance in the global.asax.  Then on the Dispose of the application (in global.asax), the previously mentioned instance of the bus would be disposed. Kind of like the abbreviated version below:

```
IBus bus;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    //Bunch of bus configuration and controller registration etc...
    //Now Create the bus and assign to a local variable so we can dispose it
    var startableBus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration);
    bus = startableBus.Start();
}

public override void Dispose()
{
    if (bus != null)
    {
        bus.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose();
}
```

But in vNext, there is no dispose in the Startup.cs that I know of.  Should an instance of the bus be held on to and disposed in some way?  Is there some other pattern that should be followed for vNext?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like you add `IApplicationLifetime` to `Configure` and then wait for `ApplicationStopping` to be cancelled.

Here is a snippet:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
   // New up/start bus here

   lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
   {
           // Stop the bus here
   });
```

Also it looks like they are planning to have a [`IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/430c55440b3528427d934c074264ef8c8cbdf739/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs#L17) so once they release that, we should be able to start the bus there.

Comment: Shouldn't the bus be running before the application has started?Sounds like this is just about asking for a race condition ... (unless there's some guarantee that requests will not arrive until all `ApplicationStarted` handlers have executed)